# Best way to create an automated email sequence?

Tags: email, automation

We've got CiviRules extension, but not sure how to build an automated email sequence that could be easily duplicated for events.

I'd rather not use "Event Reminders" because it doesn't appear we can send "Mosaico" emails using that feature.

Basically, we just want to create a 4-part email sequence using Mosaico templates.

That way, every time we have a new upcoming event, we can just edit the title, images, and subject line, then add our subscribers to the sequence.

What's the simplest way to create this sort of sequence?
Thanks guys!

Comment: Have a look at this exetnsion https://civicrm.org/extensions/mosaico-message-templates - allows you to use Mosaico templates for scheduled reminders

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Chassé](https://civicrm.org/extensions/chass%C3%A9-supporter-journeys)  That does email sequences.

Comment: That link doesn't work...

Comment: Oops - Thanks Andy, fixed now.